# Activity not Resolved when I try to open manage all files settings page?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

This works in debug mode and am not sure why it returns null in release mode. I have a save button in my application. Whenever the button is clicked then the code checks if the app has the storage manager capability and if so starts an activity for user to select a folder on where to save the image file. If the app does not have that capability then I start the settings activity to let the user grant access to the app to manage files in external storage.

I used the method Resolve Activity to check if the activity is null and unfortunately it returns true on release mode but opens the settings page for user to allow app to manage files in debug mode.
Here is the code snippet

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ActionManageAllFilesAccessPermission);
Uri uri = Uri.FromParts("package",PackageName, null) ;
//check if te activity resolved to avoid an exception
if(intent.ResolveActivity(PackageManager)! = null) {
  //start the activity for result 
  StartActivityForResult(intent, MANAGE_PERMISSION);
 }else{
   //this block is executed
  Toast.MakeText(this, "activity cannot be resolved", ToastLength.Short).Show();
 }
```

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: That is pretty bad code. You dont need to resolve an activity. Only supply the package name to the intent. Please find better example code.

Comment: @blackapps, could the PackageName be causing the method to return null?

Comment: It is nonsense code. You should not try to resolve. Second time i tell you.

Comment: @blackapps, if I cannot resolve then my app will crash from the exception

Comment: Which exception? And you should supply your package name to the intent to begin with. Use the usual code. And do not try to start that intent on a device where Android version does not support this.

Comment: @blackapps, I removed the uri bit and just supplied the action and the exception is not thrown any longer